# How Does Scalar-Tensor/Jordan-Brans-Dicke Gravity Change Orbits With Different Coupling Constants?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, quantum-gravity

My understanding is that scalar-tensor/Jordan-Brans-Dicke gravity most closely resembles general relativity as the coupling constant omega approaches infinity. I am curious about how its predictions differ from those of general relativity when the constant is less than infinity. For example, is there a threshold at which gravitational orbits might become unstable? What other discrepancies from observed behavior would it suggest?

Answer (score 2):

The tightest bounds on $\omega$ are from solar system measurements, specifically tracking of the Cassini probe, which measures the deflection of light by gravity. This difference from GR is predicted because the potential $\phi$ couples to matter fields via the trace of the stress-energy tensor, which vanishes for light. The Cassini data bound the PPN parameter $\gamma$, which in turn restricts $\omega$ to be at least $4\times10^4$.

> For example, is there a threshold at which gravitational orbits might become unstable?

This is an interesting question, but I don't know of any good discussion of how very low values of $\omega$ would work out. I think it was clear from the start that $\omega$ couldn't be $\ll 1$, so not much effort would have been put into working out such predictions. Test theories like PPN are by definition ones that only differ slightly from GR.

It was realized early on that there would be an effect on perihelion rotation, which would be scaled up from the GR value by a factor of $(4+3\omega)/(6+3\omega)$. In fact, one of the initial motivations for Brans-Dicke gravity was an apparent problem with the perihelion rotation of Mercury (which turned out to be a mistake). This supposed disagreement of GR with observation could be "fixed" by taking $\omega$ to be of order 10, but it was immediately known that one could not have $\omega \lesssim 6$.